# default @media query style

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What is the specificity on media queries?  Why does removing the media query encapsulating minimum screen widths override the media query for small screens?

```html
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  table,tr,td {
    width:100%; 
    margin:0 0 ;
/* background-color: #CCFF33 !important; */
  }

img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
  table,tr,td {  /* removing this encapsulation yields fix width for */
              margin:0 auto; /* all screens */
              width: 600px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the specificity on media queries?

Media queries have no influence on specificity whatsoever.

> Why does removing the media query encapsulating minimum screen widths override the media query for small screens?

Because the specificity is the same – both your rules use the simple element selector – it comes down to order of the rules, and the latter wins.

Comment: Thanks - **order of the rules is key here**